# Form With Inline Input Boexes

Tags: 7, forms, theming

I am trying to create a form that will have the input boxes inline and next to one another. I have created the following module but nothing seems to help. Can anyone help to solve this issue? Also the form doesn't seem to be reacting to changes in the size parameters.

```
function name_search_block_info() {
    $blocks['name_search'] = array(
        'info' => t('Name Search Block'),
    );
    return $blocks;
}

function name_search_block_view($delta='')
{
     $block = array();
     switch($delta)
     {
        case 'name_search':
          $block['subject'] = t("Search Form"); 
          $block['content'] = "<div class=\"searchform\">".drupal_render(drupal_get_form('name_search_custom_search_form'))."</div>";
          break;
     }
     return $block;
 }

function name_search_custom_search_form($form_state) {
  $form = array();

  $form['keyword'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#attributes' =>array('placeholder' => t('Search')),
    '#maxlength' => 64,
    '#size' => 32,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#id' => 'searchfield',
    '#prefix' => '<div class="container-inline">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',    
  );
  $form['location'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#attributes' =>array('placeholder' => t('Zip')),
    '#maxlength' => 5,
    '#size' => 7,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#id' => 'locationfield',
    '#prefix' => '<div class="container-inline">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  $form['#submit'] = array('name_search_custom_search_form_submit');

  return $form;
}

function name_search_custom_search_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $redirect_url = 'search/node/';
  $redirect_url .= 'type:' . $form_state['values']['type'];
  $redirect_url .= ' category:' . $form_state['values']['category'];
  $redirect_url .= ' %' . $form_state['values']['keyword'] . '%';

  $form_state['redirect'] = $redirect_url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to add prefix/suffix markup, just add a [container](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#container) or [fieldset](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#fieldset) and use CSS to float them inside.